# Можно ли прервать QSystemSemaphore::acquire()

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5, семафоры

Программа в фоновом потоке ожидает извещения от другого процесса, создав `QSystemSemaphore` и вызвав у него метод `acquire()`. При закрытии программы необходимо корректно завершить и фоновый поток. Существует ли способ сделать это (по сути, прервать `acquire()`) без генерации дополнительного ("фейкового") события?

Comment: Уточните: Вы хотите прервать `acquire()` семафора в фоновом процессе, тем самым указав ему, что пора закругляться, при активации закрытия основной программы?

Comment: Именно так. Мне казалось, что это достаточно распространенный сценарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `QSystemSemaphore` для освобождения ресурсов, занятых `acquire()` используется `release()`. Это единственный способ снять ранее созданную блокировку.

Системные семафоры (да и несистемные тоже) обычно не используются для обозначения некоего состояния процесса на время ожидания какого-либо события уровня приложения. Слово "обычно" исходит из того, что типов событий может быть множество и тогда придётся плодить под каждый из них свой собственный семафор, что в свою очередь приведёт к совершенно ненужному усложению кода.

Семафоры предназначены для однозначного доступа контекста (контекстов) выполнения к некоему разделяемому ресурсу. Состояние приложения - не их епархия.

`QSystemSemaphore` используется, например, в `QSharedMemory` предоставляющему безопасный доступ к разделяемому между процессами участку памяти. Также, при помощи `QSystemSemaphore` можно организовать безопасный доступ и к иным ресурсам. Например, к файлу, если требуется осуществлять с ним некий транзакционный набор операций чтения и записи.

Идея использования семафоров такова, что контекст выполнения одного процесса (потока) не должен блокироваться в случае, если это не помешает работе другого. Проще говоря, поработал, будь добр освободи как можно скорее. Состояние же приложения - это просто флаг, подразумевающий иногда весьма длительную неизменность, а также возможность принимать значения, не сводящиеся лишь к "доступно" и "не доступно".

Для организации межпроцессного взаимодействия, когда нужно уведомлять один процесс о состоянии другого, лучше использовать предназначенный для этой цели инструментарий. Это может быть и вышеупомянутый `QSharedMemory`, и именованные каналы (в контексте Qt - это `QLocalSocket` / `QLocalServer`).

Безусловно, для простенького процесса это может показаться избыточным, однако это, если можно так выразиться, хороший тон, как является хорошим тоном наличие в любом фоновом процессе (сервисе, демоне) обработки сигналов, поступающих непосредственно от операционной системы. Например, о необходимости закрытия процесса в экстренном случае или по причине перезагрузки машины.